# Can I use different laptop charger- similar Voltage, higher Ampere?

Tags: power, charging, voltage, charger

My original laptop charger was *output 20V 3.25A*.

Now I have a charger with *output 20V 6.75A*.

Can I use it?

(The real data: Can I charge **Lenovo Yoga 11s** with **Lenovo IdeaPad 15**?)

Comment: Are you sure it's 6.25A? As far as I can tell, Lenovo doesn't make a 125W adapter. There is a 135W adapter, though.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the point is the Ampere is different, no? Now I changing this

Comment: @fixer1234 You are right. Although my question is more precise and specific.

Comment: @bwDraco I searched before I asked, and did not find the questions you presented. So you have to take care of something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming they're both genuine Lenovo chargers with the same connector, the answer is most likely yes.

Case in point: my HP ENVY x360 13 shipped with a 45W adapter. It'll charge on a separately-purchased HP 65W adapter, with the higher output allowing it to charge *faster* than the 45W adapter when the laptop is in use. It'll also charge from any USB Power Delivery source on the USB-C port, and do so while turned on if there's at least 30W available. (It'll charge with less, but only when it's turned off or in sleep.)

---

The general rule is:

- if the voltage of the new adapter is the *same* as the one it replaces;
- the amperage is *at least* that of the adapter it replaces;
- the adapters use the *same connector*;
- and it is designed for use with your brand of laptop (but not necessarily model, as manufacturers usually design adapters with the same connector to interchange as is the case for my HP system)...

you can use the new power adapter.

---

Although this doesn't apply in your case, for laptops that charge using USB Power Delivery over a USB-C port, it's even simpler: the replacement adapter need only have an output wattage *at least* that of the adapter it replaces or what is specified by the manufacturer. You don't need to worry about amps or volts because the standard mandates that higher-output USB PD chargers support all voltages that a lower-output adapter would support.

In some cases, a laptop will accept a USB PD charger that is below specification, though it may discharge the battery under load because there isn't enough power available from the charger (as is the case with my HP ENVY x360 on a 30W adapter); or charge only when off or in sleep, not drawing power at all from the charger when turned on (which said laptop would do on a 15W adapter).

Comment: I know that W is Watt, but I don't know what this mean about Voltage & Ampere. Can you explain in your answer?

Comment: @baruchiro , Voltage is potential energy like a rock poised to fall from various heights.  Amperage is the like the total number of rocks poised to fall.  Multiplied together, those two measurements tell us the Wattage, or total electrical power passing through a conductor.  Please  see https://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/energy/question501.htm

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as long as the voltage is the same and amperage is more than required, the laptop charger will work (assuming the plugs fit)